# как позиционировать окно в правом нижнем углу экрана независимо от диагонали?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Как при запуске позиционировать окно в правом нижнем углу рабочего стола?пробовал явно задавать свойства `Window.Top` и `Window.Left`,но на разных экранах окно появляется в разных областях.`VerticalAlignment` и `HorizontalAlignment` тоже не помогают.Подскажите,как исправить проблему?

Comment: может надо у формы выставлять настройки а не у окна?

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь,WPF-приложение,какая форма?

Comment: сорри, не заметил. Left="0" а Top надо высчитывать по разрешению минус высота окна имхо

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь,не подскажете,в каком класе/поле хранится инфо о разрешении экрана?

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь,уже нашел на msdn`е.Спасибо,что откликнулись!

Comment: поделитесь решением после того как получится, может кому пригодиться

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь,вот оно:

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь myWindow.Top = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height - myWindow.Height;
            myWindow.Left = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width - myWindow.Width;

Comment: ну так вы же можете ответить сами на свой вопрос, зачем в комменты писать то

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте в конструкторе окна указать такое:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var primaryMonitorArea = SystemParameters.WorkArea;
    Left = primaryMonitorArea.Right - Width - 10;
    Top = primaryMonitorArea.Bottom - Height - 10;
}
```

Не забудьте установить `Width` и `Height`.

Comment: Перевёл в общий, т. к. ответ уже дан в комментариях.